# How to use forkJoin to wait for the completion all observable methods

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have to wait for the completion several observable method, I would like to use forkJoin for it.
Example:

```js
forkJoin(
  this.loadUserRoles(),
  this.loadDepartments()
).subscribe(result => { 
 //some logic
});

loadUserRoles() {
  return new Observable(obs => { this.userService.getRoles().subscribe(
    resp => this.loadUserRolesSuccess(resp),
    this.loadUserRolesError);
  });
}
```

LoadDepartments method looks like LoadUserRoles.
I tried to use `obs.next()` but it does not work. Is it possible to use forkJoin in this way? Is there any way to wait the completion several methods?

Comment: You are maybe looking for combineLatest ? https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

Comment: So where's the problem? `forkJoin` does wait for all source Observables to complete

Comment: `forkJoin` waits for completion of **all observables**. 

In the provided code, you didn't finalize a single observable.

Comment: @trichetriche I was thinking about this, but how to do it?

Comment: Like @ibenjelloun suggested, `combineLatest`, which is pretty self-explanatory. Also, I don't know why you're using `Observable.create`, but that's kind of a bad practice (creating an observable from an observable ? There's like half a dozen operators for that)

Comment: @trichetriche I just wanted to merge getting and processing list of departments(or users).
I thought that it would be easier to read code, i.e. we see that we have loadDepartments method and we don't care about what in this method inside.

Comment: In this case, you should use operators directly into your service. For instance, to get roles : `return this.http.get('rolesURL').pipe(tap(roles => this.loadUserRolesSuccess(roles))`. This way, your component doesn't know what the service is doing, it just calls `service.getRoles()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your `loadUserRole` to this, there really is not need to create a new Observable if there's no complex stuff going on in your `loadUserRoles`

```
loadUserRoles() {
       return this.userService.getRoles().pipe(
                map(res=>this.loadUserRolesSuccess(res))
               ,catchError(e=>this.loadUserRolesError(e)))
}

 forkJoin(
    this.loadUserRoles(),
    this.loadDepartments()
 ).subscribe(([result1,result2]) => { 
 //some logic
 });
```